# Why is my Python code, to learn about "if" statements, failing to work?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to learn more about `if` statements. I tried to create a program that asks the user to enter amounts of beer and outputs different answers when the amount increases. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

What I expect to happen is when I type in the number eg. 5 the result should be "Beer is awesome." because it's lower than 50. And if I type in 60 it should output "That's a lot of beer." because it's higher than 50 and lower than 100.

I've read the Python documentations and still don't figure it out. This is my code:

```
print "How many cans of beer do you want?"

beer = raw_input("Enter your amount: ")

if beer >= 1:
    print "Beer is awesome."
elif beer >= 50:
    print "That's a lot of beer."
elif beer >= 100:
    print "You're drinking way too much beer, man."
else:
    "Did you make a choice larger than 100? If yes, then you're crazy!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw_input returns a string, you should convert to an int to do math/operations with it.

```
beer = int(raw_input("Enter your amount: "))
```

Also, always mention what goes wrong/against your expectations in your post, in this case it's easy to see but with more complex code it gets hard quickly what the actual problem is.

Edit: There's another problem with your program, but I think you'll be able to figure out that one on your own when you run it without errors.

Comment: Thank you Azeirah! It worked out well. Yes i will mention this in the future.

Comment: @Cybe just in case, the other problem is that any value >= 50 or >= 100 is also >= 1, since those conditions are on `elif` clauses those blocks will never be executed.

Comment: @Azeirah yes i figured that out and as i commented in Daans answer. I used <= instead of >=. It works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that raw_input returns a string -= 
to make numeric comparisons to the value returned yiou have to convert it to `int`.

try changing your input line to 
`beer = int(raw_input("Enter your amount: "))`  instead

Comment: That code line is funny. You didn't change anything at all =)

Answer (score 0):

You should use upper bounds instead of lower bounds, otherwise your first if is always true and you get "Beer is awesome."

```py
if beer < 50:
    print "Beer is awesome."
elif beer < 100:
    print "That's a lot of beer."
elif beer < 500:
    print "You're drinking way too much beer, man."
else:
    "Did you make a choice larger than 500? If yes, then you're crazy!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what your `if` statements do.

```
if beer >= 1:
```

Which means that when the value of `beer` is larger than or equal to one, the following code is executed.

```
elif beer >= 50
```

`elif` is a keyword that you can find in other languages as "else if". It means something like: if the previous statement was false (else) but the following is true (if), execute the following block. Which means that you only get the output "That's a lot of beer." when `beer >= 1` is false, and `beer >= 50` is true - which is never, because `beer` can't be smaller than 1 and larger than 50 at the same time. The same holds for the other `elif` statements.

You may get the last output, "Did you make a choice larger than 100? If yes, then you're crazy!", when all other statements are false - in other words, when `beer` is equal to or less than zero.

I hope you understand how you can get the correct statements now, to get what you want.

Comment: Thank you Daan. I've figured it out and put <= instead of >= and added a new elif and removed the text in the else: `if beer <= 10:
 print "Beer is awesome."
elif beer <= 50:
 print "That's a lot of beer."
elif beer <= 100:
 print "You're drinking way too much beer, man."
elif beer >= 100:
 print "Did you make a choice larger than 100? If yes, then you're crazy!"
else:
 print ""`